# Regex match nth occurence

Tags: regex, perl

I'm trying to achieve a regex where I could get the value between pipes stating which occurrence it should match, it's important that it works with perl.

So, if I have the following string: `GASD|11111|AAASAS|12WSD1|3SDSD&USJ|` I would be able to get `GASD` or `11111` or `AAASAS` and so on depending on the nth match I want.

I was able to get to: `(?:([^|]*)\|){4}` and despite working with other languages, it's not working with perl, it grabs everything from the first until the 4th match `GASD|11111|AAASAS|12WSD1`.

Appreciate new ideas.

Comment: exactly what you want?

Comment: `perl -wE 'say "GASD|11111|AAASAS|12WSD1|3SDSD&USJ|" =~ /(?:([^|]*)\|){4}/'` outputs `12WSD1`, not the whole string up to it.

Comment: @choroba weird... I'm using a closed source solution, which asks for te string and regex and supposedly using perl... that's probably the issue here. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of matching n-th occurrence of a string segment (between `|` chars),
you can split the string.

Assume that you have your text in `$x`.

```
my $x = 'GASD|11111|AAASAS|12WSD1|3SDSD&USJ|';
```

Then you can split this string on `|`:

```
my @tbl = split /\|/,$x;
```

and then refer to any element of this array.